# Clear timeout that's active

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery ajax where I use `setTimeout()`. Sometimes, the user triggers the ajax multiple times, before the `setTimeout()` has kicked off.

So is it possible to clear an active version of the `setTimeout()` that was triggered previously by adding `clearTimeout()` like this:

```
clearTimeout(time);

var time = setTimeout(function() {
   $('#hello').fadeOut();
},2600);
```

Or maybe I need to add some form of global variable?

Comment: Yes, if you declare `time` at a higher scope.

Comment: You answered the question by yourself with the last sentence. ;)

Comment: @eisbehr Please elaborate. How do I add a global variable in my case?

Comment: Put `var time` in global scope - ie. outside of the event handler you're running under

Comment: Just declare `time` variable outside of your ajax handler. Basically.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan At what point specifically?

Comment: I don't know, you haven't shown enough of your code for anyone to tell you

Comment: Got it, got it! Let me test this bad boy.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have put `var time = "";` outside of the ajax function, and also at the very top of my JS file, and `clearTimeout()` is still not cancelling. Do you have any further input?

Comment: Did you remove the `var` keyword from your inner scope?

Comment: Show your code so we can see the scopes, we can keep telling you to put the variable in different places but until we know what scope the ajax call is in, then we won't know if the time variable is global enough

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Solved it. The problem was that I was running `clearTimeout()` on `success:function()` when I should have run it on `beforeSend:function()`. Headache resolved. Thank you all. =D

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're doing you may want to act on the first click and ignore subsequent clicks until the first one is finished, or you way want to reset the timer and only act 2.6 seconds after the last click... I gave examples of both, let me know if anything needs clarification..

```js
(function() {
  let time, btn = document.getElementById('btn1');
  btn.onclick = function() {
    if (time) clearTimeout(time);
    time = setTimeout(function() {
      alert("what the stink?!");
    }, 2600);
  }
})();

(function() {
  let time, btn = document.getElementById('btn2');
  btn.onclick = function() {
    if (time) return;
    time = setTimeout(function() {
      alert("what the butts?!");
      time = null;
    }, 2600);
  };
})();
```

```html
<button id=btn1>Only reacts to last press</button>
<button id=btn2>Only reacts to first press</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example which answers your question and illustrates the wonder of closure.

```
document.getElementById('inputBox').addEventListener('keyup', Delay());

function MyFunction(){
  console.log(this.value);
}

function Delay(){
    var timer = 0;
    return function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(MyFunction.bind(this), 1000);
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tlynch001/7y3vnfjn/